# Rowid not in order when insert into an oracle table

Tags: oracle, rowid

first,I create a table

```
create table TEST
(
  id   VARCHAR2(11),
  name VARCHAR2(11)
)
tablespace USERS
  pctfree 10
  initrans 1
  maxtrans 255
  storage
  (
    initial 64K
    next 1M
    minextents 1
    maxextents unlimited
  );
```

Then I insert ,delete ,insert some data,and watch the result:

```
truncate table test;
insert into test values (1,1);
commit;
insert into test values (2,1);
commit;
insert into test values (3,1);
commit;
delete test where id = 2;
commit;
insert into test values (4,1);
commit;
insert into test values (5,1);
commit;
insert into test values (6,1);
commit;
delete test where id = 5;
commit;
insert into test values (7,1);
commit;
insert into test values (8,1);
commit;
insert into test values (9,1);
commit;

select t.*, t.rowid from TEST t
```

then I can see the query result is :

```
"ID","NAME","ROWID"
"1","1","AAAGXqAAEAAAAP+AAA"
"8","1","AAAGXqAAEAAAAP+AAB"
"3","1","AAAGXqAAEAAAAP+AAC"
"4","1","AAAGXqAAEAAAAP+AAD"
"6","1","AAAGXqAAEAAAAP+AAE"
"7","1","AAAGXqAAEAAAAP+AAF"
"9","1","AAAGXqAAEAAAAP+AAG"
```

You can see the second line is `8`,but I insert `8` after `7`,it should appear after `7`.Seems the order of the rowid is not same as the order of the insertion.
So in my real project,I insert the last data,but it do not appear at last,but jump to the middle space,then my customer can not find the last data.
My question is, the order of rowid can not be  guaranteed when insert data,right?Or I must add an order field?

Comment: If you read [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CREATE-TABLE.html#GUID-F9CE0CC3-13AE-4744-A43C-EAC7A71AAAB6) carefully, you'll find that  this is explicitly stated apart from general convention in relational model: *HEAP indicates that the data rows of table are stored in no particular order. This is the default.* And it is also worth to check the [concepts](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/cncpt/index.html) for brief overview of Oracle's internals.

Comment: As others have already said, there is no ordering of rows in a heap table. If you want a result set in a particular order then you _must_ use an appropriate ORDER BY clause.  In addition, you mention ROWID. You need to understand that ROWID has absolutely nothing to do with any presumed ordering of rows.  It is the actual, physical address of a row - a combination of the object (table) id, the data block within the file, the row within the block, and the file id.  Check the doc, [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns008.htm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't rely on `ROWID` as it can be changed. For example, if you export schema and then import it back, `ROWID` might change so - if your code relies on (wrong) assumption that it is *constant* - code will break and you'll have a problem.

Use something else as an identifier and a value to sort rows in a table. For example, a sequence.

Answer (score 1):

There is no internal order to a SQL table, in the sense that when Oracle executes your query, it is free to return records in any order whatsoever.  The way to impose an order to the result set is to add an `ORDER BY` clause to your query, e.g.

```sql
SELECT t.*, t.rowid
FROM TEST t
ORDER BY t.ID;
```